# Python polar plot

Tags: python, plot, errorbar

I'm total new in Python, but I must do polar plot in it.

I found this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)

r =  np.array([3.21,3.03,2.69,2.13,1.58,0.98,0.52,0.14,0.03,0.00])

theta = 2*np.pi/360 * np.array(list(range(0, 100, 10)))

ax.plot(theta, r, "ro")
ax.errorbar(theta, r, yerr=0.1, xerr=0.05, capsize=0)

plt.show()
```

I must do few changes. In the array I want to have 36 values, but when I tried to add it I got this error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

I have also question about error bars, 'yerr' is error of value in 'r' array.
Is 'xerr' error of angle in radians?

Comment: Please show your changed version, not the original.  When you changed the array length, did you also change the length of the np.array for theta?

Answer (score 2):

You must have the same dimension for theta and r.
Here len(r) = 10 and len(theta)=10

So for example:
if you have 36 values in r theta could be:

```
theta = 2*np.pi/360 * np.array(list(range(0, 360, 10)))
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe the values need to be closer together.

Comment: No, I can't help you for that, sorry